# Using jasmine-spec-reporter instead of wdio-spec-reporter with webdriverio?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, jasmine-spec-reporter

I've just started using webdriverio. All good mostly, except frustratingly when I have multiple assertion failures in a single test, the spec reporter only logs the first one (even though I've proven that the rest of the spec runs, and all assertions that should fail, do fail). Googling suggests a) this is as expected of wdio-spec-reporter, and b) not the case with jasmine-spec-reporter.

So I've tried to get jasmine-spec-reporter set up as a custom reporter. I have:

a) Installed jasmine-spec-reporter (a good start!)
b) Added a require statement as appropriate, together with defining a reporterName - as found at https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/2077
c) Added this reporterName value to my reporter array.

When I then run the test, nothing errors (in terms of the custom reporter, the assertions still fail!) - but the spec reporter produces no output at all. Not a single line!

Most of what I've read on line refers to self-written custom reporters, and mentions requiring 'util' and 'event' modules - which as far as I can tell jasmine-spec-reporter doesn't use. Is this the problem? Has anyone gotten jasmine-spec-reporter working with webdriverio before? And more importantly, how?!

TIA

Answer (score -2):

`jasmine-spec-reporter` can only work with `jasmine` tests and by default `webdriverio` do not use `jasmine`.

I have not tested it but there is a `webdriverio` plugin for `jasmine` that could be helpful to use `jasmine-spec-reporter`: https://github.com/webdriverio/wdio-jasmine-framework.